# ¿Como detener foreach en php a través de ajax?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hola a todos tengo un problema con un `foreach` en `PHP` el cual lo llamo desde una petición `Ajax`. Dentro de este hay varios cálculos a partir de `select`, se hace un `insert` de cerca de 8000 registro, el punto es que tarda varios minutos en realizar ese proceso, y si llegado el caso, el usuario quiere detener dicho proceso no se puede. He intentado a través de `session` o con `ajaxstop();` pero no logro detenerlo, es decir hasta que no termine de ejecutarse el `loop` de `PHP`, no puedo ejecutar otra función en `php` para detenerlo. cabe aclarar que utilizo el framework CodeIgniter.

Aquí esta el código resumido, de lo que realiza en PHP.

```
class Calculo Extends CI_controller{

    public function index(){
     $this->load->view('calculo.html');
    }

    public function calbase(){
    set_time_limit(0);
    $post1 = $_POST['XXXX'];
    $post2 = $_POST['XXXX'];
    //se crea el registro en la base de datos (si se realiza el insert ingresa al loop)
    if($this->meta_model->insertme_p($dato)){

                    // recorre todo el array
                    foreach ($todos as $key => $n) {

                                // en este primer foreach se insertan datos en una tabla 

                                // escribo temporalmente un archivo que leo a travez de ajax, con el porcentaje de registros que lleva
                                    write_file(FCPATH . 'temp/calc/procal.txt',$this->porcentaje($cant,2));

                                    foreach ($n as $key_t => $ray_t) {
                                        // en este segundo foreach se insertan datos en otra tabla,
                                        // dependiento del contenido del array multidimensional que se recorre en el primer foreach 
                                }

                        } 

        }

    // finalmente cuando termina retorno un true al ajax, para confirmar 
    echo true ;
   }
  }
```

a traves de ajax.

```
 $('#boton').on('click', function(){
       $.ajax({
            data:  parametros,
            url:   '/calculo/calbase.php',
            type:  'post',
            success:  function (r) {
                console.log(r);  
            }
    });
 });
```

Espero haberme hecho a entender.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, sera que puedes colocar el código sería de gran ayuda para poderte dar una respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voy a dejar dos posibles métodos para parar un `foreach` en PHP a través de un AJAX. Uno de los métodos es usando sesiones (explicaré por qué no te funcionaba) y el otro es siguiendo un enfoque similar al de la [respuesta de Shaz](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/8380/250) (usando ficheros auxiliares) aunque con un estilo algo distinto.

### Método 1: Usando sesiones

> Nota: Lo que voy a sugerir no es la manera más correcta. De hecho, recibirás un mensaje de aviso "*Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent*" (puedes usar `error_reporting(0)` al principio de tu página para evitarlo, aunque eso es seguir el método del avestruz: realmente no solucionas el problema, sólo lo ignoras).

¿Por qué no te funcionaba al usar sesiones? Porque estás usando sesiones en las dos páginas y se bloquean entre ellas: por defecto PHP escribe los datos de la sesión en un fichero que se abre con `session_start` y que se bloquea para evitar ediciones concurrentes. Por eso cuando haces la llamada AJAX, tiene que esperar a que termine la otra página: porque uno de los recursos (el fichero de sesión) está bloqueado.

Una solución para esto: limita al mínimo el entorno en el que se utiliza la sesión en el fichero PHP en el que tienes el `foreach`. En lugar de hacer [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) al principio de la página, hazlo dentro del `foreach` que quieras romper y cierra la sesión (o mejor dicho el fichero de la sesión) usando [`session_write_close()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php). De este modo, el fichero de sesión sólo estará bloqueado mientras compruebas el valor que decide si el `foreach` debe parar o no.

El fichero que contiene el `foreach` se vería así:

```
<?php

    // Aquí las operaciones que tengas que hacer antes del foreach

    foreach ($todos as $key => $n) {

        // Inicia la sesión
        session_start();
        // Comprueba el valor que indica si se ha pedido que se pare el foreach
        if (isset($_SESSION["stop_foreach"]) && $_SESSION["stop_foreach"] == true) {
            // elimina el valor de la sesión (para permitir que el foreach corra de nuevo)
            unset($_SESSION["stop_foreach"]);
            // sal del bucle foreach
            break;
        }
        // salva y cierra el fichero de sesión
        session_write_close();

        // Aquí las operaciones que tengas que hacer dentro del foreach
    }
```

> Nota: Es importante que borres la variable de sesión relacionada con la parada del `foreach`, si no lo haces, podrías tener problemas porque el `foreach` quedaría bloqueado durante todo el tiempo que dure la sesión.

El fichero PHP que se llama con AJAX (calbase.php) sería así:

```
<?php

    // Los cálculos que tengas que hacer

    // Añade una variable de sesión
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["stop_foreach"] = true;
```

Al seguir este método **corres el riesgo de que otra página modifique la sesión y la "corrompa" al actualizar los valores de manera concurrente**... pero realmente eso es lo explotas para solucionar el problema, aunque no deja de ser un riesgo.

---

### Método 2: Usando un fichero auxiliar

En lugar de usar sesiones y correr los riesgos que se explican arriba, puedes usar ficheros en el servidor. La idea es similar, lo único que cambia es cómo se hace:

1. En el fichero llamado por AJAX, crea un archivo auxiliar (usando [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)) que se utilizará de controlador. El contenido realmente no importa, la idea es que si el fichero existe, el `foreach` debe parar.
2. En el fichero del `foreach` comprueba si el fichero existe usando [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php). Este método tiene la ventaja de que sólo se comprueba si el fichero existe, no se abre y no se tiene que leer el contenido.
3. Si el fichero existe, rompe el bucle, pero antes borra el fichero usando [`unlink()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php).

El fichero que contiene el `foreach` se vería así:

```
<?php

    // Aquí las operaciones que tengas que hacer antes del foreach

    foreach ($todos as $key => $n) {

        // Comprueba si el fichero auxiliar existe
        if (file_exists("stopforeach.txt")) {
            // si existe, bórralo
            unlink("stopforeach.txt");
            // y rompe el bucle foreach
            break;
        }

        // Aquí las operaciones que tengas que hacer dentro del foreach
    }
```

El fichero PHP que se llama con AJAX (calbase.php) sería así:

```
<?php

    // Los cálculos que tengas que hacer

    // Crea el fichero que indicará que debe pararse el foreach (el contenido no importa)
    file_put_contents("stopforeach.txt", "stop");
```

En el ejemplo de arriba asumo que los dos ficheros PHP están en el mismo directorio; pero pueden estar en diferentes directorios, lo único que tendrías que hacer es cambiar las rutas del "stopforeach.txt" para que apunten al mismo lugar.

Answer (score 1):

Asumiendo que ambos archivos estén en el mismo directorio (y en el mismo servidor obviamente). También puede ser implementado en un controlador, servicio, etc.

ciclos.php :

```
<?php
// antes de iniciar el foreach, crea un archivo de cancelación
file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/myscriptcancelfile', 'run');

// en cada iteración, revisa el archivo
for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
    echo 'hola<br>';
    if ( file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/myscriptcancelfile') != 'run' ) {
        exit('Script cancelado') ;
    }
    sleep(2);
}

echo 'fin';
```

Desde otro script o método llamado por el botón `parar proceso`

parar.php :

```
<?php

file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/myscriptcancelfile', 'stop');
```

Tomado de https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847462/how-do-i-stop-a-php-script-running-on-the-background

Comment: No entiendo para que necesitaría accesos adicionales a los que ya tenga, si lees la adaptación que hice, dice: 'desde otro script o método', lo cual quiere decir que los dos procesos pueden estar en el mismo archivo incluso. En caso que se necesiten dos archivos distintos, si pude subir mi archivo con el llamado inicial, también puedo subir otro archivo con la segunda parte.

Comment: Si te fijas en la pregunta que hacen en inglés, se refiere a que la persona no puede reiniciar el servidor web para 'matar' el proceso, de ahí vienen todos esas respuestas y comentarios que nombras. No tiene nada que ver con php esa parte la verdad. Digamos que una cosa es matar el proceso infinito y otra como poder pararlo en futuras ejecuciones.

Comment: del modo que comenta Shaz, yo lo utilizo para ir leyendo el progreso de los registros, php escribe el progreso en el archivo temporal y ajax lo lee.  intentare hacerlo para detener el loop.

Comment: no funciono, el sistema sigue esperando a que el loop termine, sola hasta entonces cambia el archivo con el 'stop', aun ejecutando el script desde otro controlador de codeigniter.

Comment: Son dos procesos distintos, el segundo es el que cambia el valor en el arhcivo, no debería interferir. Puedes imprimir en cada iteración el valor del archivo, para ver que está leyendo el if.

Comment: he intentado ver que que hace el sistema con la validación del archivo temporal  hasta con ob_flush(); pero no se ejecuta hasta que no termine el loop, es más, he abierto una nueva pestaña en el navegador llamado directamente a la función para que cancele y se queda cargando hasta que el loop termina.

Comment: Lo acabo de probar en mi servidor local y me funciona de maravilla, voy a editar mi respuesta.